# difference for and while loops file i/o

Tags: c, for-loop, file-io, while-loop

i write a code which takes values from text file and write in a text file, so I'm stuck on for and while reading end of file i think both of codes are right there is no any difference btw them,however I get difference. I'm unable to understand. Besides is there other way to read eof ? Thank you all appreciated answers.

```
for(st=(fscanf(fptr_in,"%c",&ch));
                st==1;
                st=(fscanf(fptr_in,"%c",&ch))){
```

the other

```
st=(fscanf(fptr_in,"%c",&ch));
    while(st==1)
            st=(fscanf(fptr_in,"%c",&ch));
```

Comment: what is this , man ?

Comment: Clean up the code please

Comment: This code does not compile. Whats with the random indentation? Whats with the trailing `{`?

Comment: i think you can get what happening in code clcto i just wonder difference btw them in the used way

Answer (score 1):

The conditionals are different. In the `for` you are using the return value of `fscanf` which is an `int`. When an `int` is used as a conditional, it is the same thing as `!= 0`:

```
int x;
if( x ) {} 
//equiv to:
if( x != 0 ){}
```

In the `while` loop, you explicitly check if the return value is a `1`. So, if you change your `for` loop to

```
for( (st=(fscanf(...)) == 1 )
```

(or conversely remove the `==1` from the `while` loop) they should produce the same behavior.